# Stop Google Analytics refere spam

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

Ive been getting an awful lot of refer spam in my Google Analytics referrer traffic recently (as i guess most people are - sites like www.Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com, buttons-for-your-website.com etc)

Is there a way to stop this ? Is there a different tracking code that i could use or is there a way i can remove / ignore certain sites from the referral report ?

Comment: The best way to stop it is by adding a valid hostname filter in GA, this will  prevent most of the spam without needing to add a filter every time you can find more info for this solutino here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362